# Joining a table more than once causes huge performance drop

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a pretty big query.

The performance has always been reasonably acceptable, but I now have this problem.

I need to join a table more than once, using aliases of course, but doing so causes a massive performance hit.

It's a huge query so I won't post it all but here's the gist:

```
SELECT table1.name,
       ALIAS1.CODE AS "Sequence"
...
FROM table1
...
LEFT JOIN table2 ALIAS1
ON ALIAS1.COLUMN1 = table1.key1
AND ALIAS1.COLUMN2 = 'aaba'
AND ALIAS1.COLUMN3 = '00001'
...
```

This one is fine, running in about 90 seconds. But if I add the same table again as in the following, execution time increases exponentially (so far 2 hours and still running):

```
SELECT table1.name,
       ALIAS1.CODE AS "Sequence",
       ALIAS2.CODE AS "Rating"
...
FROM table1
...
LEFT JOIN table2 ALIAS1
ON ALIAS1.COLUMN1 = table1.key1
AND ALIAS1.COLUMN2 = 'aaba'
AND ALIAS1.COLUMN3 = '00001'

LEFT JOIN table2 ALIAS2
ON ALIAS2.COLUMN1 = table1.key1
AND ALIAS2.COLUMN2 = 'ffhr'
AND ALIAS2.COLUMN3 = '00107'
```

What I need to know is, what factors could be causing this?

It looks to me like the indexes should be ok otherwise the first join would be a problem.

Why would the second join be such an issue?

I actually need to join the same table a third time, but obviously this is a no-go as things stand!

Comment: If you have access to execution plan it will reveal the problem.

Comment: Yep wouldn't it just? No DBA's here until Monday and nobody else has access, unfortunately :(

Comment: Is it possible you have a typo somewhere -- say, maybe you accidentally have `ALIAS1` somewhere where you need `ALIAS2`, or that sort of thing -- that's resulting in an enormous cross-join?

Comment: How many rows are matching in each alias? You are essentially cross joining table2, i.e. supposing there are 1,000 rows in table2 with column1 = 'aaba' and column2 = '00001' for table1.key = 1, and another 1,000 rows in table2 with column2 = 'ffhr' and column3 = '00107', then your query goes from 1,000 rows for table1.key1 = 1 to 1,000,000 rows. This increase could be affecting the execution plan (I'd say you'll have to wait until monday for a definitive answer I'm afraid).

Comment: Can we have the schema definition for that table, I believe the indexes will show us what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ON ALIAS1.COLUMN1 = table1.key1
AND ALIAS1.COLUMN2 = 'aaba'
AND ALIAS1.COLUMN3 = '00001'
```

When you join on three columns simultaneously, you should have a multi-column index that includes all three columns.

Perhaps instead of joining on constant values, you could put those filters in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Be aware that putting the filters in a where clause is not synonymous with putting them in the join condition when it is an `OUTER JOIN`. Unless `NULL`s are accounted for it will turn the `OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: There is one index on the table, actually with 4 columns. However one of them is always an empty string, and none are ever null. Should I include this as well? Oh -and I'm not able to add/alter indexes :(